# loop through list with sublists javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

ul
     li1
     li2
     ul3
      li3.1
      li3.2
      ul3.3
       ul3.3.1
       ul3.3.2
     li4
     li5

and I must check all items in ul3 I can't be sure if there is only two or three or more lists

Comment: Thanks I'll try your solutions and I've found appropriate word (at least a hope so :)) I need to check one branch of the tree Beginning from "this" and to the last leaf and I appologise for my bad English I'm currently improving it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know what you mean by "check", but you can have a function be called for each `<li>` like this:

```
$('li').each(function() {
  // whatever "check" means
});
```

With just plain Javascript:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
  var li = nodes[i];
  // check ...
}
```

*edit* — well it's not clear what exactly you need, but if you just need to inspect `<li>` elements in lists that are themselves in `<li>` elements, then you'd just code that into the jQuery selector:

```
$('ul ul li').each(function() { ... });
```

Comment: +1 plain JavaScript, since native loops are always faster then JQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) like this:

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
  // your code.....
});
```

This will loop through the ul children at any nested level.

**Update:**

> and I must check all items in ul3 I
>   can't be sure if there is only two or
>   three or more lists

Try this in that case:

```
$('ul:eq(2) li').each(function(){
  // your code.....
});
```

This will start from third ul and find its children at any nested level.